# JPA: Is it possible to perform queries on a byte[] field?

Tags: database, jpa, type-conversion, lob

i have a Measure entity with a byte[] field that contains the data of the measure.
Data format changes according to

```
public enum Format {
    BOOLEAN,
    INT,
    INT_ARRAY,
    FLOAT,
    FLOAT_ARRAY,
    TEXT
}
```

Is it possible to perform queries on the database like:

```
select measure m from Measure where m.type=MeasureType.INT and SOMESORTOFCONVERSIONFUNCTION(m.data) > MINIMUM
```

or should i fall back to have a field for every type of data?

Comment: How does your datastore support that? (you havent said which one)

Comment: I have hibernate with h2 or mysql, is this useful?

Comment: useful to you to go to the docs for mysql or h2 and see what SQL FUNCTIONs they provide for such an operation ... because any JPA provider will only ever use what the datastore provides